# Jquery modal gallery не работают две колонки

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Всем добрый день. Столкнулся такой  проблемой. Создал модальное  окно с переключаемыми изображениями и со слайдером для галереи. Проблема в том, что при  нажатии на блоки column 2 column 3  в  модальном окне  изображается только блоки column 1. Помогите разобраться. Заранее спасибо.(Вместо картинок поставил цвета).

Вот код:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".row .column .image").click(function() {
    $("#ModalGallery #modal-content #modal-image").css("display", "none");
    $(" #ModalGallery #modal-content #modal-image").eq($(this).index()).css("display", "block");
    $("#ModalGallery").show();
    $(".closemodal").click(function() {
      $("#ModalGallery").hide();
    });
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#modal-content #modal-image").each(function(e) {
    if (e != 0)
      $(this).hide();
  });

  $("#next").click(function() {
    if ($("#modal-content #modal-image:visible").next().length != 0)
      $("#modal-content #modal-image:visible").next().show().prev().hide();
    else {
      $("#modal-content #modal-image:visible").hide();
      $("#modal-content #modal-image:first").show();
    }
    return false;
  });

  $("#prev").click(function() {
    if ($("#modal-content #modal-image:visible").prev().length != 0)
      $("#modal-content #modal-image:visible").prev().show().next().hide();
    else {
      $("#modal-content #modal-image:visible").hide();
      $("#modal-content #modal-image:last").show();
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
.row {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 3em 1em 3em 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: orange;
}

.column {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 0 4px;
  margin: 0.2em;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 8px;
  padding: 3em 1em 3em 1em;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#ModalGallery {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: black;
}

#modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 50%;
}

#modal-image {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5em 1em 5em 1em;
}

.closemodal {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#prev,
#next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 1em;
  margin-top: -50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

#next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

#prev {
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

#prev:hover,
#next:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column 1">
    <div class="image" style="background-color:red;"></div>
    <div class="image" style="background-color:yellow;"></div>
    <div class="image" style="background-color:orange;"></div>
    <div class="image" style="background-color:blue;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="column 2">
    <div class="image" style="background-color:black;"></div>
    <div class="image" style="background-color:white;"></div>
    <div class="image" style="background-color:indigo;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="column 3">
    <div class="image" style="background-color:violet;"></div>
    <div class="image" style="background-color:blue;"></div>
    <div class="image" style="background-color:red;"></div>
    <div class="image" style="background-color:green;"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="ModalGallery">
    <span class="closemodal ">&times;</span>
    <div id="modal-content">
      <div id="modal-image" style="background-color:red;"></div>
      <div id="modal-image" style="background-color:yellow;"></div>
      <div id="modal-image" style="background-color:orange;"></div>
      <div id="modal-image" style="background-color:blue;"></div>
      <div id="modal-image" style="background-color:black;"></div>
      <div id="modal-image" style="background-color:white;"></div>
      <div id="modal-image" style="background-color:indigo;"></div>
      <div id="modal-image" style="background-color:violet;"></div>
      <div id="modal-image" style="background-color:blue;"></div>
      <div id="modal-image" style="background-color:red;"></div>
      <div id="modal-image" style="background-color:green;"></div>
      <a id="prev">&#10094;</a>
      <a id="next">&#10095;</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Код   грамадний . Если  требусется  разяснение скажите  .

Comment: Если убрать  `<div class="column"></div>`   то работает норамально .Но без  них вид  проподает